# Automatically setting height for a covered background image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

On [this website](http://altushealthsystem.com/dev/), I'm using the CSS3 `Cover` property of the `Background` rule to stretch an image behind the header.

Right now, I had to set the `header` element to have a `min-height` of `500px` for it to work. However, this is not an optimal solution because when I resize the window, I expect the height to be less so the image shrinks proportionally. I'm thinking the solution might be in Javascript?

Here is the code:

```
<div style="background: url(http://altushealthsystem.com/dev/wp-content/uploads/home-banner.jpg) no-repeat 0 0 transparent;background-size: cover; min-height: 500px;"></div>
```

[Link to the JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TseEz/)

Is this possible?

Comment: If possible, can post `html`, `css`, `js` ? Thanks

Comment: It's live in [here](http://altushealthsystem.com/dev/), please let me know if you still need me to post the html/css.

Comment: If possible, can post `html`, `css`, `js` at original post ? Thanks

Comment: Done, I also added a link to the js fiddle I created.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need javascript for that. You could specify the header height using percents. However that will work only if the parent has specified height.

In your example you should add

```
height: 100%;
```

for `html` and `body` elements (all ancestors of header), and for example:

```
height: 40%;
```

for you header element.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of declaring a background for the header, you can add an image element with the following styling:

```
<header....> 
<img src="http://altushealthsystem.com/dev/wp-content/uploads/home-banner.jpg" style="max-width:100%; height:auto;position: absolute;z-index: -999;">

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row top-row">
...
```

You should also take advantage of the @media tags to declare a certain width and height when the screen is of certain size.

Comment: I think yours is a better solution than my background solution. Thanks

Comment: I do however still see an issue where my content is now hidden below that image.

Comment: You should fix that using z-index. [Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index)